# positioning a div bottom of the page and keep content above

Tags: css

I have the following CSS which positions a div at the bottom of the page.

*Q:* How can I stop content flowing underneath it?

```css
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background:url(../images/bg-footer.jpg) top;
    z-index:200;
    height:34px;
    width:100%;
    line-height:34px;
    padding:0;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I can't add padding to the body or anything because I have a fullscreen background image in place as per this tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using: `position:absolute;` instead?

Comment: This doesn't work, because when i start scrolling the page this also starts scrolling.

Comment: You have the footer div as the last div inside the body?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the content **above** your footer you should start by removing the positive `z-index` from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the footer as the final div of the page (perhaps wrapped in a full page div) then try setting the clear property to both in your css, eg:

clear: both;

Which should prevent any other divs from falling below the footer.

Comment: Quite possibly. I followed the accepted link above and it has clear: both; at one point.